# magnific popup background appears for full screen and closes as one clicks anywhere

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

when I click on link that activates magnific popup ajax call, the grey background appears for full screen. however I am trying to see if background is just enough to cover login form (inside the pop up). Also wherever I click inside ajax form it automatically closes. Need help pls...

```
 <a class="simple-ajax-popup-align-top" href="result.php">try me</a><br>
```

jquery Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    alignTop: false,
    overflowY: 'scroll'
});
});
```

and result.php is as follows:

```
    <div class="login_body">
     <form id='login' name="login" method="post" action="login_process.php" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

    <div class="field_container">Email:</label>
    <input type='text' name='cust_email' id='email'  maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; /></div> 

    <div class="field_container">Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='cust_password' id='password'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; /></div>

    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login' />



    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `closeOnContentClick: false` to your code, like that:

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    alignTop: false,
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    closeOnContentClick: false
});
```

Check the documentation for more options: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html